# Transposing regression table in Latex

Tags: r, regression, transpose, stargazer

I have a regression table in latex that is the result of output from applying the stargazer package on my regression results in R. I am wondering how to transpose the table such that the columns switch place with rows. In other words, I want the Lags to be where the variables are and vice versa.

Moreover, I am wondering how to reduce the space between the first and second columns as well as how to add a vertical line between columns. I've tried adding | in between, but sometimes this doesn't cover well and leaves in some space in between the top and bottom hline.

```
\usepackage{dcolumn}
 \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Regression results} 
  \label{} 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{lD{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2}} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Characteristics} \\ 
\cline{2-7} 
 \\ 
 Lags: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Variable 1 & -1.14^{***} & 0.04 & -1.73^{***} & -0.24 & -0.59 & -1.64^{***} \\ 
  Variable 2 & 0.16 & -0.25 & 0.12 & -0.12 & 0.14{**} & 0.04  \\ 
  Variable 3 & 0.46^{*} & -0.61 & 0.17 & -0.98^{***} & -0.32 & -0.09\\ 
  Variable 4 & -0.02 & -0.005 & -0.03^{***} & -0.32 & -0.11 & 0.015 \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{6}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question: do you just want to know how to edit *this particular block* of LaTeX code to get what you want, or are you trying to influence some procedural output in R for lots of tables like this?

Comment: Yes, I want to edit this particular block in order to get it transposed. @AaronMontgomery

Answer (score 0):

So, a few LaTeX basics:

(1) LaTeX is unsophisticated. In R, you can transpose a table or matrix or whatever with `t()`; there is no such analogue in LaTeX. (Caveat, maybe it exists in a package or something, but personally I wouldn't trust such an approach.)

You'll have to manually retype the table -- or, alternatively, convince R to massage the table *before* passing it to LaTeX output. Since you didn't discuss any R code, I'll skip over any discussion about that and focus on the LaTeX part.

(2) The building blocks of the `tabular` environment are: `//` breaks to a new line, and `&` (the alignment indicator) skips to a new tab. So if you have a table like

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f
\end{tabular}
```

the only way to get its transpose is just to retype it:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c}
  a & d \\
  b & e \\
  c & f
\end{tabular}
```

The number of columns is denoted by the markings immediately after `\begin{tabular}`; for instance, `{c c c}` indicates three columns, all centered. In yours, the `D` tab stands for a column aligned to a decimal point per the `dcolumn` package, so you'll need to remove two of these when you transpose your table since you'll have four column variables instead of six. After that, it will just come down to a matter of retyping the contents of the matrix.

For your other questions:

> I am wondering how to reduce the space between the first and second columns

That's an interesting one that seems not to be contained to the code you posted. When I posted that exact same code into an empty LaTeX document, it didn't have that spacing that yours has; what this means is that the table is being ballooned out by some *other* code, most likely to justify out to a given page width or something. I can't help since I can't reproduce the artifact, but you might try enclosing the entire code block with `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`, maybe? This might let LaTeX break the rules of how big the box containing this table is supposed to be. That's a total guess, though, and the folks at https://tex.stackexchange.com/ might be able to help more on that issue.

> as well as how to add a vertical line between columns. I've tried adding | in between, but sometimes this doesn't cover well and leaves in some space in between the top and bottom hline.

First response: [consider not doing vertical lines at all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/why-not-use-vertical-lines-in-a-tabular).

Second response: You've got the right idea, but the reason it's leaving breaks is that you don't have enough alignment tabs (`&`) in certain lines. For instance, putting `|` between the third and fourth `D{}{}{}` in your `tabular` options makes this monstrosity:

[image: ugly, even for a vertical line]

So, what went wrong? Referring to the regions I annotated in blue:

A: When you break a line with `\\`, it only print vertical alignment bars if you put the proper number of column advancement tokens. Fix by replacing the line `\hline \\[-1.8ex]` immediately before Variable 1 with `\hline & & & & & & \\[-1.8ex]`. (One `&` per desired column advancement!)

B: In this case, the use of `\multicolumn` overrides any other vertical alignment options. Fix by replacing

```
 Lags: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} \\
```

with either

```
 Lags: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} \\
```

or

```
 Lags: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} \\
```

and note where the `|` was in either of the two fixes.

C: Same issue as A. Fix by replacing the `\\` immediately after the `\cline{2-7}` with `& & & & & & \\` to advance through columns and render vertical markers.

D: Don't do anything here, obviously.